# 1V Overshoot and Undershoot on Power Rails of LTE Module

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, noise, buck, electrolytic-capacitor

I have designed a PCB (four layer) having `SIM7600I` LTE Module. The Stackup is:

1. Signal & Component Layer with Ground Pour
2. Internal Ground Power Plane
3. Internal Power Power Plane (3V3, 4V and 1V8)
4. Signal & Component Bottom Layer with Ground Pour

The datasheet says:

[image]

I have followed the datasheet guide and included approx. `700uF` capacitors (considering the load transient response of `AP6503` as it can handle the transient with 200mV voltage drop):

[image]

I have been using `AP6503` Buck Converter to step down from 5V to 4V. The schematics of power design specially for `LTE` module is given below:

[image]

And I have placed 700uF capacitors near to Module's Power Pin.

[image]

The Power traces from `Buck Converter` to LTE Module is on Internal Power Plane (Layer 3).

[image]

After assembling the PCB and testing it, I found out it is working perfectly but after few days, I put probe of my oscilloscope to the power pin of LTE module and saw weird undershoot and overshoots. I am not sure the culprit behind it. The spikes are of 1V. I want to resolve this issue in my next iteration but I am not sure who is the culprit. I have been using these capacitors near to power pin of LTE Module.

1. [470uF Aluminium Polymer 11mohm 16V](https://katalog.we-online.com/pbs/datasheet/875115357006.pdf) X 1
2. [100uF Tantalum 100mohm 16V](http://datasheets.avx.com/TPS.pdf) X 2
3. 100nF Ceramic Capacitor X 1
4. 33pF Ceramic Capacitor X 1

The pictures of the noise on power pins of LTE Module are:

[image]

[image]

**I want help in understanding what I did wrong. I think I have followed the datasheets and took measures to avoid any problem after PCB fabrication. Please help.**

Comment: Please show your probe setup. Probing with a large inductance ground lead will cause red herring oscillations.